# Sitecore Web Forms drop list linkage

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a question about the Drop List field type of Sitecore Web Forms for marketers.

I want to build a web page which has two drop lists that are connected. When the first one changes, the other one's data changes based on the selected value of the first one.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible out of the box. You will need to build a custom WFFM field that will store the 2 droplist. If you need more information on how to build custom WFFM fields you can checkout [this blog post](http://elenazlateva.blogspot.com/2012/09/custom-field-type-for-sitecore-web.html).

Comment: A word of advice on this, having just done it myself (although not in WFFM)... One, use an existing tool if you can.  Lots of implementations of cascading DropDownList out there.  Two, if you must roll your own, go either completely client-side driven or completely server-side with your DropDownList objects inside an UpdatePanel.  Mixing client-side/server-side logic here is an ASP.NET nightmare.  The UpdatePanel works very well here, it just won't be as snappy as a client-side only implementation.